# Why do I get an error when trying to put JavaScript in my chrome extension?

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I am wanting to make a simple chrome extension. It is very simple Javascript.
Here is the Javascript:

```js
function popup(){
   alert("Hello");

}
```

And here is the HTML:

```html
<button onclick = "popup()">Click me!</button>
```

It is very embarrassing that this does not work.
Here is the error I get:

Refused to execute inline script because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src 'self' blob: filesystem:". Either the 'unsafe-inline' keyword, a hash ('sha256-jl7zkecItBHATwzPa5aa7MfGZ7nKUEQQCaXwXyPlRI4='), or a nonce ('nonce-...') is required to enable inline execution.

Please help very frustrated.

Comment: The error is telling you that the site has a content security policy setup to disallow inline script statements.  And it is also telling you how to fix it.  https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CSP

Comment: Can you share your manifest?

Comment: {
 "name": "Ad be gone!",
 "version": "1.0",
 "description": "Blocks google ads",
 "permissions": ["webRequest", "webRequestBlocking", "<all_urls>"],
 "browser_action": {
  "default_icon": {
   "16": "favicon.ico"
  },
  "default_popup": "popup.html",
  "default_title": "Ad be gone"
 },
 "background": {
  "scripts": ["background.js"]
 },
 "manifest_version": 2
}

Comment: Move all your Javascript code to an external file and do not use any inline code (which includes your `onclick = popup()` code) . See the [documentation](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/contentSecurityPolicy#JSExecution)

Comment: How would I execute code with an onclick then?

Answer (score 0):

The error is being caused because the extension has a content security policy that prevents inline javascript. In order to solve this error, do the following:

HTML

```
<button id="btn">Click me!</button>
```

and add this to the bottom of your body tag inside of the same HTML file:

```
 <script src="test.js"></script>
```

JS (create another file called test.js)

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {
    let chosenButton = document.getElementById('btn');
    chosenButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
    alert("Hello");
 })
});
```

Comment: Now it gives me this error:  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Comment: @Landon I found out the problem! I edited my answer. You can try that instead :)

Comment: Thank you it works! So can I just add any code here as well?

Comment: @Landon You can add any code that refers to the elements inside of the HTML file containing <button id="btn">

Comment: I am actually using this to make an ad blocking extension. Without functions I don't know how to make an on-off button for the ad blocker. Here is the code:                       chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest.addListener(
  function(details) { return {cancel: true}; },
  { urls: ["*://*.doubleclick.net/*", "*://*.ads.google.com/*",]  },
  ["blocking"]
);
I would mean alot if you could help

Comment: @Landon Sorry about that. You can also make functions and call them during a specific event.